# Load spatio-temporal dataset with R spacetime

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile

With the R package `spacetime`, I would to create a dataset of class `STFDF`. I have observations for n times at m locations (n x m). The locations are US states.

I managed to load the n times:

```
"2000-01-01 EST" "2000-02-01 EST" "2000-03-01 EST" "2000-04-01 EST" ...
```

And a matrix with n columns and m rows. I also loaded the US states into a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`:

```
df = loadMyDataFrame( ... ) # my US dataset
times = extractTimes( df )
matrix = extractMatrix( df )

# load US states from a shapefile
library(maptools)
crswgs84=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
# class: SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
states <- readShapePoly("data/cb_2015_us_state_500k/cb_2015_us_state_500k",proj4string=crswgs84)

library(spacetime)
STFDF(states, times, data=matrix)
```

Doing this, I get:

```
Error: nrow(object@data) == length(object@sp) * nrow(object@time) is not TRUE
```

Clearly, the `states` are not sorted and filtered correctly. How can make sure that the rows in `states` match the columns in `matrix`?